# What's the difference between 'test' and evaluating with /dev/null?

Tags: shell-script, test

I noticed different `.sh` scripts for homebrew which check whether it's installed.

One uses this syntax:

```
if test ! $(which brew); then
```

The other uses this syntax:

```
if ! which brew > /dev/null; then
```

I get that they are both checking the exit code for `which brew`, but I'm curious as to whether there are other differences between them. To me, the former is clearer, and I would assume (maybe incorrectly) more efficient since it doesn't have to redirect any output.

Also, why does the second actually execute `which brew`, regardless of whether the output is sent to `/dev/null` or not? Just how shell works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is a clumsy hack, the second is a common mistake.

These two tests do something completely different, which happens to produce the same outcome.

> ```
> if test ! $(which brew); then
> ```

This tests whether the **output** of `which brew` is empty.

- If `brew` is on the search path, then `which brew` produces a word of output, so the `test` command receives two arguments: `!` and the path to `brew`. When `test` has two arguments, the first of which is `!`, it returns true if the second argument is empty (which isn't the case here) and false otherwise.
- If `brew` isn't on the search path, then the output of `which brew` is empty, so the `test` command receives a single argument which is `!`, so `test` returns true.

Note that this command will produce an error message and a failure status if the path to `brew` contains whitespace, because [that's what an unquoted command substitution means](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). It so happens that a failure status was the desired outcome here, so this works in a roundabout way.

This command does not test the exit code of `which brew`. The exit code is ignored.

> ```
> if ! which brew > /dev/null; then
> ```

This is the straightforward way to test if `which brew` succeeds. It doesn't depend on anything brittle except `which` itself.

`which brew` is always called in both cases. Why would it matter that the output is redirected to `/dev/null`? “Hide this command's output” does not mean “don't run this command”.

The proper way to test if `brew` is not available on the command search path is

```
if ! type brew >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
```

See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: this makes sense - after reading the linked question, it seems the only case in which 'which' might fail is if there's an alias or function in ~/.bashrc or ~/.cshrc

my question re: output redirection...thinking abstractly, if I said to you 'If you run around a mile, I'll give you $10' doesn't actually cause you to run a mile. And in other coding languages I'm familiar with, 'if' statements don't actually execute the conditional statement. I'm just curious why the statement is actually executed here!

Answer (score 1):

#### Part one `if test ! $(which brew); then ...`

1. If you run `which brew` your `$PATH` is searched for an executable called `brew`. If one is found the name is printed to stdout. If nothing was found an error message is printed to stderr. (Some shells provide a builtin `which` that also reports builtins and shell functions, reserved words, .... For example `zsh`.)
2. `$(...)` captures the *stdout* (but not the stderr) of whatever the `...` shellcommands are and puts it on the command line as argument(s).
3. `test ! ...` returns the inverted return code of `test ...`. That is `test`'s way of negating an expression. `test ...` (without any options in the `...` part) just tests if the `...` part is not the empty string.

**Result**: `which` is used to look for an executable called `brew`. The resulting path or an empty string is put on the command line as an argument to `test !` which checks if this argument is the empty string and thus returns `0` (true).

#### Part two `if ! which brew > /dev/null; then ...`

Here `which brew` is the same as above. If `which` finds an executable it not only prints the name but also returns with code `0` (true). If it doesn't find anything it prints an error message and returns some other code (false). This code is inverted by the shell because of the `!` in front of the command (`0`->`1`, anything else -> `0`). That is what `if` cares about. Because the user does not care to see the actual path of `brew` the standard output of `which` is redirected to `/dev/null`.

#### Notes:

In both cases the stderr of `which` is not redirected and should be visable on the terminal.

I did not test it but I assume that the second form is faster as it starts only one process/builtin. But both commands do redirection: The second one explicitly to `/dev/null`, the first one less obvious (at first) by capturing the output of `which` with `$(...)`. You can roughly compare the speed with something like [the `comp` function I use](https://github.com/lucc/shell-config/blob/master/functions/comp).

There are man pages for `which` and `test`. And the man page of the shell (`sh`, `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`) has a section about redirection and command substitution, as well as on builtins (not only `which` but also `test` is often implemented as a builtin).